# Ionic Side Menu With Role Based Authentication

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I just learned ionic with angularfire. I'm trying to create authentication with roles from this [site](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-side-menu-role-authentication/). i have 3 role = admin, member and guest. I want to combine it with angularfire, by taking data from the realtime database, like this

```
  "profile" : {
    "MsTCKbUfNsRhcEtAl3pEHdy70Rw1" : {
      "firstName" : "test",
      "role" : "admin",
      "lastName" : "test",
      "userName" : "test"
    },
```

and this auth.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

  currentRole: Roles;
  roleRef : Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.roleRef = afDatabase.object('profile').valueChanges();
    }

  role(roleRef: string) : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.roleRef === 'admin') {
        this.currentRole = {
          role: 0
        };
        resolve(true);
      } else if (this.roleRef === 'member') {
        this.currentRole = {
          role: 1
        };
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  }

    isAdmin(): Promise<void> {
      return this.currentRole.role === 0;
    }
```

This code gives:

> TypeError: "this.currentRole is undefined"

please help me finish this, or give me another tutorial for authorization. If I forget to give another information please let me know, I'll edit it

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: TypeError: "this.currentRole is undefined". i dont know how to resolve this

Comment: Hmm... I don't immediately see what is causing that. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: i hope so, or if u have any solution for me sir? to make authorization.